# What are the semantics of move in rust?

Tags: rust

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let counter = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));
    let mut handles = vec![];

    for _ in 0..10 {
        let counter = Arc::clone(&counter);
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut num = counter.lock().unwrap();
            *num += 1;
            println!("Inner counter: {}", Arc::strong_count(&counter));
        });
        handles.push(handle);

        // println!("Inter counter: {}", Arc::strong_count(&counter));
    }

    println!("Outer counter: {}", Arc::strong_count(&counter));

    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }

    println!(
        "Result: {}, {}",
        *counter.lock().unwrap(),
        Arc::strong_count(&counter)
    );
}
```

Why can `Inner counter` and `Outer counter` output, but `Inter counter` will report an error?

**If I uncomment `Inter counter`, the rust compiler tells me:**

```
let counter: Arc<Mutex<i32>>
Go to Arc | Mutex

borrow of moved value: `counter`
value borrowed here after moverustcE0382
main.rs(10, 36): value moved into closure here
main.rs(11, 27): variable moved due to use in closure
main.rs(9, 13): move occurs because `counter` has type `Arc<Mutex<i32>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

If `counter` has been moved inside the closure at `theread::apawn`, why can the outside still use it?

I'm not sure whether this is caused by the `move` keywords.

Comment: You should avoid using variable names that are already declared. It leads to confusion

Comment: bill.gates: This is very debatable and the above code is one of the patterns where shadowing is commonly used in Rust. (Changing the type while keeping the data being the [other](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html#comparing-the-guess-to-the-secret-number).)

Comment: Do not post the errors from your IDE. Run `cargo check` in the terminal and post the full error.

Comment: `Do not post the errors from your IDE. Run cargo check in the terminal and post the full error.` I'm sure this is a good suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If counter has been moved inside the closure at theread::apawn, why can the outside still use it?

Because you have two completely different variables with the name `counter`:

```rust
    let counter = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));
```

and

```rust
        let counter = Arc::clone(&counter);
```

The second one gets `move`-d inside the closure, but the first one only gets borrowed during the iteration in order to clone it.

When the second counter gets created, it *shadows* the first one for the rest of the loop's body. So your code is semantically the same as:

```rust
    for _ in 0..10 {
        let counter2 = Arc::clone(&counter);
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut num = counter2.lock().unwrap();
            *num += 1;
            println!("Inner counter: {}", Arc::strong_count(&counter2));
        });
        handles.push(handle);

        println!("Inter counter: {}", Arc::strong_count(&counter2));
    }
```